# Load pdf file by php (slow)

Tags: php

i have a script where i load the pdf file using php, but the problem is i notice that it takes some time to load, and the pdf file isnt so heavy, also my internet connections is fast, is my code not optmized enought?

Here it is:

```
ob_start();
$pdf = $_GET['download_file'];
$urlPDF = "http://domain.com/candidates/".$pdf;
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; 
filename='.$urlPDF);
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($urlPDF));
readfile($urlPDF);
exit;
```

Comment: just because you have a fast connection doesn't mean everything is going to be fast. what if `domain.com` is having a bad day? plus, you're buffering the entire pdf, so what you're sending out to YOUR client won't happen until `exit;` is reached. Remove the ob_start() and your client should start getting bytes at the same rate that readfile is receiving them from domain.com

Comment: You have to understand that by doing that, the pdf file has to travel twice. Once to the server from its original source, and once again to the user...

Comment: @MarcB i just removed the ob_start(), but then gives me a error Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in download.php on line 6, "Warning: Cannot modify header information" and "Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://"...

Comment: @MarcB found the problem, but now is downloading the file instead of opening in the browser and for some reason the filename downloaed is the same of the url.

Comment: Resolved the issue instead in the "Content-disposition" being attachment i replaced it by "Content-disposition: inline"

Comment: your warnings are killing your headers. you cannot stat a url, and sending out a url as the filename for the client is also wrong.